# Can someone help me on this SQL Query to return the ID not found in SQL IN Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The SQL Query is this:

```
SELECT * from ActiveListing a WHERE [seller-id] in 
(SELECT id from Product p where PurchaserID = 60741 and right(id, 4) = '-XRU')
```

The result of the 2nd Select Statement if run returns 1000 id's that will be used by the 1st Select statement, that if run returns 800 records which is correct.

The Question:

How would I change this query in order to get the 200 id's that has no result

RDMS:
MS SQL

Sample:

```
 SELECT id from Product p where PurchaserID = 60741 and right(id, 4) = '-XRU'
```

return ids (1,2,3,4)

```
 SELECT * from ActiveListing a WHERE [seller-id] in (1,2,3,4)
```

returned two records
ids 1 and 2 return a value
ids 3 and 4 return nothing

I wanted to get the id's 3 and 4

I hope I made my question a little clearer, and I appreciate everyone who is trying to help.
I'm still testing other suggestions

Comment: What RDBMS? Microsoft SQL? MySQL?

Comment: [probably] [ms-sql], [given] [the] [silly] [brackets].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to a) Ask a meaningful question in the subject ("Can someone help me with this query?" is not a useful search phrase for future readers here) and b) include information about which DBMS you're using (syntax and functionality differs between the different database systems). Thanks.

Comment: What version of SQL Server, please?

Comment: Clarify -- you want the entries in Product that are matched by the criteria: RIGHT(id,4) = '-XRU' AND PurchaserID = 60741 but DO NOT have an associated entry in ActiveListing? If so then my answer is good. If not then my answer is rubbish

Comment: @ErikE Version is SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Randy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17095920/57611), you can just change `IN` to `NOT IN`. However, I would encourage you to start thinking in terms of JOINs and `EXISTS` (semi-joins):

```
SELECT
   A.* -- try to use explicit columns though instead of *
FROM
   dbo.ActiveListing A
WHERE
   Right(A.[seller-id], 4) <> '-XRU' --may improve performance
   AND NOT EXISTS ( -- this is actually an anti-semi-join
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.Product P
      WHERE
         P.PurchaserID = 60741
         AND Right(P.id, 4) = '-XRU'
         AND A.[seller-id] = P.id
   )
;

SELECT
   A.* -- try to use explicit columns though instead of *
FROM
   dbo.ActiveListing A
   LEFT JOIN dbo.Product P
      ON P.PurchaserID = 60741
      AND Right(P.id, 4) = '-XRU'
      AND A.[seller-id] = P.id
WHERE
   Right(A.[seller-id], 4) <> '-XRU' --may improve performance
   AND P.id IS NULL
;
```

Note my addition that "may improve performance' also eliminates any `NULL` values, so adjust accordingly if `A.[seller-id]` can be `NULL`.

If I have understood this backward and you want the rows from `Product` that aren't in `ActiveListing` we just flip the tables and conditions:

```
SELECT
   P.* -- try to use explicit columns though instead of *
FROM
   dbo.Product P
WHERE
   P.PurchaserID = 60741
   AND Right(P.id, 4) = '-XRU'
   AND NOT EXISTS ( -- this is actually an anti-semi-join
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.ActiveListing A
      WHERE P.id = A.[seller-id]
   )
;

SELECT
   P.* -- try to use explicit columns though instead of *
FROM
   dbo.Product P
   LEFT JOIN dbo.ActiveListing A
      ON P.id = A.[seller-id]
WHERE
   P.PurchaserID = 60741
   AND Right(P.id, 4) = '-XRU'
   AND A.[seller-id] IS NULL
;
```

Comment: upvoted for the helpful and informative comments -- however I don't think it's what the OP wants!

Comment: It looks like you were right, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ErikE I will still have to verify your solution if its return the right id's

Comment: There's one more solution  `P.id != ALL (SELECT seller-id from dbo.ActiveListing )` although its pretty much the same as `NOT IN`

Answer (score 4):

a little unclear - but try `NOT IN` instead

```
SELECT * from ActiveListing a WHERE [seller-id] not in 
(SELECT id from Product p where PurchaserID = 60741 and right(id, 4) = '-XRU')
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually answering what the OP wanted -- but what the OP wanted is a little unclear. I think they were looking for the entries in Product that aren't matched by the seller-id's in ActiveListing. -- Thought about downvoting but I think the original question is pretty unclear.

Comment: @Randy I'd tried using the NOT IN statement but it returns all the record in the ActiveListing minus the result of the 2nd Select statement

Comment: @deric try my solution -- sounds like it's what you are after

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to find the entries in product that fit the criteria

1) last 4 characters of id are -XRU
2) PurchaserID = 60741
3) There is no ActiveListing that matches that ID

Then I'd suggest

```
SELECT p.Id
FROM Product as p
WHERE p.PurchaserID = 60741
  AND RIGHT(p.id,4) = '-XRU'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ActiveListing AS a
    WHERE a.seller-id = p.id
    )
```

though you could also use a NOT IN for the NOT EXISTS clause (but I don't think that's as declarative) or even a LEFT JOIN and check for NULLS (but again that's not as declarative)

Output Id's

```
SELECT p.Id AS [CheckID]
FROM Product as p
WHERE p.PurchaserID = 60741
```

Output Distinct Id's

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Id
FROM Product as p
WHERE p.PurchaserID = 60741
```

Check the rowcounts are the same -- if they are not then it may be that there is NO ROW that would not have a corrosponding entry in ActiveListing

Alternate Query Worse Performance Version -- but must Vanilla SQL

```
SELECT p.Id AS [CheckID]
FROM Product as p
WHERE p.PurchaserID = 60741

EXECPT
SELECT seller-id AS [checkID] FROM ActiveListing
```

There is nothing logically that can go wrong here -- if you run the query and you get no results then... there are no results..

Comment: I think the rows he wants are from `ActiveListing`, not from `Product`, but we'll have to see what the OP says.

Comment: I tried this but the query return nothing

Comment: @deric -- so if you run the query without the NOT EXISTS you get back 1000 rows? is it possible that Id on Product is not unique?

Comment: you can think of NOT EXISTS as a row level predicate -- for every row in the outer query it will evaluate the inner query and discard or keep a row based on that -- if you have duplicate id's then it's entirely possible that you have *no* rows that match the criteria you have specified.

Comment: based on your updated post I am at a loss to see why the sql I posted didn't work for you.

Comment: @TransactCharlie I have not yet tested your solution with the NOT EXISTS, sorry for the slow response but can you edit the query without the NOT EXISTS

Comment: @deric -- huh? what do you mean?

Comment: @TransactCharlie you said a while ago to try to run the query without the NOT EXISTS right?

Comment: @deric -- I simply meant run the query without the NOT EXISTS -- just comment out the clause if you want to do that... But the only reason to do that was so you could confirm that the information from the rest of the query was as you expected. Easy way to check would be to run the query without the NOT EXISTS clause and then run the same QUERY but use the SELECT DISTINCT p.ID -- check that the row counts are the same. If they are not then you have duplicate Id's

Comment: @TransactCharlie I tried removing the NOT EXISTS clause and run the query it returned 1000 records same as running with distinct

Comment: @deric -- then I'm at a loss. I can't see anything logically wrong with the query. Don't think I'm going to be able to help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would change IN to NOT IN.